# Excel VBA Extracting Inner Text from href Tag

Tags: html, excel, href, innertext, vba

the HTML CODE look like this:

```html
<div class="WebPageMessage">
<div class="WebPageMessageInformation">
<div class="Message">Your request has been scheduled. <a href="/MyAccount/QueuedJob.aspx?JobID=221816">Job # 221816. Click here To monitor Schedule</a><br>There are 0 job(s) already in the queue.</div></div></div>
```

Desired result: Extract the text "Job # 221816..."

here is the code im trying to use but i am getting "object is no supported" error msg
`Set foo = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("Message").getElementsByTagName("a").innerText`

Any help would be great
Thanks and happy holidays : )

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are attempting to `Set` a string (innerText) to an Object. Also, you need to specify which Class Name "Message" you want and which tag name "a" you want.

You have two options:

### Option 1: Set the object first, then grab string from `foo`

```
Dim foo As Object, myStr As String
Set foo = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("Message")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
myStr = foo.InnerText
```

### Option 2: Don't assign the object to a variable and just grab the string directly.

```
Dim myStr As String
myStr = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("Message")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText
```

Notice how I placed `(0)` after the `ClassName` and `TagName`? That is subject to change dependent entirely on your full HTML code. Best method would be using a `For Each...Next` statement to iterate through all the ClassNames or TagNames, but you can specify which Class/Tag Names you want specifically by placing (i) after. Notice the 's' after getElement**s**...? That's because class and a tag names are not unique. The only unique element is the ID (notice no 's' in `getElementByID()`.